# Override onLeft and onRight handlers in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native

I found how to override the onLeft and onRight handlers for the buttons in the NavBar with `react-native-router-flux` inside my component. So when I `console.log()` in there I see the output. However, I cannot seem to find a way to pass props (and thus my state) into there.

I cannot access them via `this.props` since they are required to be static methods. Any idea? I just want to dispatch an action but I need the `dispatch` function which is not available inside the handlers (I am using `redux`)

```
class ProfileSettings extends Component {
  static rightTitle = "Save";
  static onRight(...props) {
    console.log('right!') // logs 'right' when pressed
    console.log(props)    // logs an array of the connect function (react-redux) + an empty object
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute in an entirely custom NavBar with `static renderNavigationBar`, which allows you to use a connected component. Here's an example with a logout button:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {NavBar} from 'react-native-router-flux'

class SettingsNavBar extends NavBar {
    renderRightButton () {
        return <Button title="Button" onPress={this.props.logout} style={styles.settingsRightButton}>
            <Text style={styles.rightButtonText}>Logout</Text>
        </Button>
    }
}

const ConnectedNavBar = connect(null, {logout})(SettingsNavBar)

export class ProfileSettings extends Component {
    static renderNavigationBar (props) {
        return <ConnectedNavBar {...props} />
    }
    // your component here...
}
```